# Datetime field in XML gets an hour added for some reason when storing in database via SSIS

Tags: sql-server, xml, datetime, ssis, xsd

I have an XML that I'm pulling in, which has datetime fields:

```
<startTime>2015-11-01T00:00:00-05:00</startTime>
<endTime>2015-12-01T00:00:00-05:00</endTime>
```

The relevant portion of the XSD is as follows:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.foo.com/bar" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
....
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="startTime" type="xs:dateTime" />
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="endTime" type="xs:dateTime" />
```

When I process the file using SSIS, I'm using an XML Source component that fetches data from the file and loads it into a table.

For some strange reason, when the load into the table is done (and this only happens when I use 2015-11-01 as the start date), the startDate field gets an extra hour added to it. It appears as follows in the table:

```
2015-11-01 01:00:00.000
```

This only happens when using November 1st 2015 as the startDate, I'm assuming it's because the DST change was on November 1st, setting time back (I'm in eastern time zone) but if anything, it should have impacted things at 2:00am, subtracting one hour, and not adding.

I'd appreciate any help in figuring out why this is happening. Thanks!

Comment: SQL column type is date, isn't it? In addition, is it possible to know what library is used to put the xml data into the database?

Comment: Probably [related querstion on dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28187/how-can-i-get-the-correct-offset-between-utc-and-local-times-for-a-date-that-is)

Comment: @sergioFC The column is datetime. I'm not using a code-based library to import, I'm using SSIS. The XML Source component is used to get the file, then certain transformation steps are done (none involving the startDate field) and then loaded via a OleDB destination component. Similar to the following link except with some merge and sort operations before the loading step: https://i0.wp.com/blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/files/2012/06/image_613.png

Comment: As far as I know dateTime type doesn't contains information about the timezone (dateTimeOffset type does). At `2015-11-01T00:00:00-05:00` the DST had been completed on timeZone 0. Maybe the time is incorrectly transformed to `05:00:00-00:00` instead of `04:00:00-00:00`, then stored as a number in the databes and when it is shown in your local time zone the hour value is 01. I wish I know if the value shown (`2015-11-01 01:00:00.000`) can refeer to two different moments because `01:00` "happened twice". I am not an expert on SQL nor time but I am puzzled so I am gonna offer a bounty.

Comment: What is your timezone set to?  Is it set correctly in your SSIS process?  If you can set it, does changing it make any difference?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I figured it out - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out there wasn't an issue at all - I feel so stupid!

I'm under the Eastern Time Zone in Canada, which observes Daylight Savings. During the summer, the clock moves ahead one hour and the offset becomes GMT-04:00. During the winter, the clock is adjusted back an hour and the offset becomes GMT-05:00.

The file that was coming in had specified the startTime and endTime as:

```
<startTime>2015-11-01T00:00:00-05:00</startTime>
<endTime>2015-12-01T00:00:00-05:00</endTime>
```

However, the DST did not end until November 1st 2:00am. Therefore the offset for the startTime should have actually been:

2015-11-01T00:00:00-**04:00**

At midnight, the startTime was still adhering to the summer schedule, in saving the hour (hence offset -4:00). The endTime was after the time change so the offset was specified correctly as -05:00.